# Create Dictionary Method with parameters

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am pretty sure you can tell what I am trying to do from the code but my syntax is obviously off...

I want a method that will return a Dictionary but also accept some parameters...

```
      private Dictionary<string,Term> (SPField fld)
            {
                 var terms = new Dictionary<string, Term>();
...do something...                 
return terms;
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question ? What do you want to do with the parameter ?

Comment: what do you want fld to do here?

Comment: Well first off you need to name your method.

Comment: It would probably help for you to *name* the method. So far, I see an access modifier, a return type, and an argument list. No name.

Comment: how would we know, what you want your code to do?

Comment: @Yogendra - Jedi mind reading of course

Comment: Sheesh, you guys are rabid today. I guess it's my fault. It was a brain fart question.

Answer (score 3):

`return` must be all lower case.  It can't have a capital "R".

Your method has no name:

```
private Dictionary<string, Term> MethodNameGoesHere(SPField field)
{
    var terms = new Dictionary<string, Term>();
    return terms;
}
```

Comment: also, the parameter to this method never gets used at all.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen That's more to do with how the method is implemented.  From the question I gather he's just trying to get the shell to compile before starting to implement it.  Without knowing what he wants to do, we can't really propose an implementation.

Comment: @Servy shouldn't it also be `Dictionary<string, Term> terms = new...`?  I don't think this will compile.

Comment: @Hogan It does compile.  I compiled it.  Have you never seen the `var` keyword?  I suggest you look into that if you haven't.

Comment: @Servy - Excellent, you win the snide award for today.

Comment: @Hogan How is that snide?  You asked a question, I answered it.  I'm sincerely shocked if you've never seen the `var` keyword before, I wouldn't think I'd need to explain it to you.

Comment: @Servy - On every version of .NET?  In any case, I believe there are instances where returning a var to another type won't work, thus my comment.  I'm not going to bother finding them for you - I'm sure you can yourself.

Comment: @Hogan `var` was added in C# 3.0 which was...a while ago.  `var` is completely different from `dynamic`.  `var` has completely static typing.  It is simply allowing the compiler to infer the type of the variable based on the type of the expression initializing it.  It will compile into the exact same IL code.  There is *no* situation in which using `var` is any different than manually entering the type of the expression used to initialize the variable.  Go ahead and try to find an example; none exist, provably so.  Again, if you aren't familiar with `var` I suggest you go look it up.

Comment: @Servy - right, thinking back on it I believe the issue I had was "fixed" with the addition of Covariance and Contravariance auto casting, but it was a while ago and I don't have a 3 or 3.5 installed so I can't make you a test case easily.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're trying to do is create a function that takes a parameter and returns a dictionary then you are pretty much already there.

```
private Dictionary<string, Term> MyFunc(SPField field)
{
    var terms = new Dictionary<string, Term>();
    \\code to do stuff goes here
    return terms;
}
```